# Scanner for Windows Malware

Tags: windows, scanner, malware

I have an Ubuntu PC, and would like to copy some files to a windows PC. Before I do this, I would like to scan these files for malware, which works in windows.

Is there an Ubuntu virusscanner for windows viruses?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered an alternative approach? How about copying the files to a pen drive or similar first then check the files on the Windows system malware scanner before committing to the Windows platform?

Comment: There are also large commercial scanners like _avast!_ existing for both Windows and Linux/Ubuntu. They offer a free version for both systems, you only need to register. No payment. Just if you don't get along with ClamAV...